# Java Beginner - What is wrong with my method?

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner and I'm trying to create a really simple method in NetBeans, and I'm frustrated that this doesn't work. Can someone point out my errors?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    /**
 *
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
    public String critMeth(String name){
        String c = name + " loves you!";
        return c;
    }
    String critter = "Henry";
    String love = critMeth(critter);
    System.out.println(love);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In java you don't declare methods in methods. Change that to

```
public String critMeth(String name){
    String c = name + " loves you!";
    return c;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String critter = "Henry";
    String love = critMeth(critter);
    System.out.println(love);
}
```

And don't forget you can only call static methods from static methods if you don't call them on receiver objects. So make the first method static (I let that as an exercise to you).

Comment: Cool. That helped with most of it. I put the static in critMeth and that cleared up issues it was having with calling on that method in main. My only issue now is that Netbeans doesn't see the main method anymore. I can't get it to see it either. I went into the project properties > selected Run, and it had my class listed there, but when i click browse, it says no main methods found..

Comment: BTW.. Thank you for the help so far

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String critter = "Henry";
    String love = critMeth(critter);
    System.out.println(love);
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
private static String critMeth(String name){
    String c = name + " loves you!";
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Understanding static and instance member<br>http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/java/java3.php

Answer (score 0):

The main method is the method java will run if you press start. It is not allowed to place a method inside of another method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String critter = "Henry";
    String love = critMeth(critter);
    System.out.println(love);
}

public String critMeth(String name){
    String c = name + " loves you!";
    return c;
}
```